# Calculus Question that should be really easy

Tags: calculus, kinematics

I know that the derivative of a distance function is velocity. That is, if a car has distance function $f(t)=t^2$ then at time $t$ it's velocity is $2t \text{ m/s}$. So let's say I observe some particle that appears to moving along the graph $f(t)=e^t$ towards positive infinity. I can easily calculate it's distance function from the fixed point $(0,1)$ on the graph. This is just $$\|(t,e^t)-(0,1)\|=\sqrt{t^2+(e^t-1)^2}$$The derivative of this function can be easily computed. But what is it representing? It can't be the velocity of the particle, because I have no idea how the particle is moving and I haven't given any initial conditions. So what is the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello user and welcome to StackExchange!

To answer your question the derivative literally measures "the rate of change of" the function being derived.

In this case you are literally measuring "the rate of change of distance from the point (0,1) at a given time t).

This quantity is a scalar (meaning number without reference to direction) so velocity in the formal sense is ruled out, but it still encodes the idea of how 'fast' the particle is moving away from a given point in simpler terms

"the speed with which the particle moves AWAY from the point (0,1)"

Notice that if hypothetically our particle starts to run circles around the point (0,1) the velocity indeed may not be zero but the speed-moving-away is (since the distance is fixed).

Hopefully that clarifies what is being measured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems completely arbitrary, I mean let's say the particle is moving at a constant acceleration with speed $100 \text{ m/s}$. Now suppose that it still has constant acceleration but speed $10 \text{ m/s}$. Give me a time $t$ and I compute the velocity by just plugging in $t$ to the derivative. Why will the answer change?? Do you know what I mean? By plugging in $t=5$ I will get the same answer regardless of the particles speed, won't I?

Comment: sorry about the lateness of answering this, could you clarify exactly what you mean? (just explain a bit more thoroughly) I don't think I understand.

Comment: I actually believe I figured it out, it's probably not worth going into the details. But thank you for your help and your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As *frogeyedpeas* explained, the derivative is the rate of change of distance from the point (0,1). A policeman's radar gun measures exactly that: it measures how quickly you are headed toward or away from the policeman, but it does not measure any movement sideways. If you drove in a circle around the policeman, the radar gun would measure zero speed. So your physical meaning is the speed measured by a radar gun at the point (0,1).

Comment: Can a radar gun measure tangential velocity? The velocity of the car at one point on the circle?

Comment: I don't think a radar gun can measure tangential velocity as such, just the "radial motion" directly toward or away from the observer. "Proper motion" sideways is not measured in this way. That terminology is from astronomy, where the radial motion of stars or galaxies can be measured by red shift.